# cross-origin read blocking (corb) blocked cross-origin error OpenLayers Offline Map with tileserver-gl-light server

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-7

I want to use offline Map for my openLayers project , I am using openLayers 7 and a mapTiler file ***mbtiles*** and TileServer GL light for  serving my map ,
I use this code

```
const raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new XYZ({
    url:
      "http://localhost:8080/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf",
  }),
});
```

but I faced with this error

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <URL> with MIME type application/x-protobuf. See <URL> for more details.
```

I want to use my server map